# Incorrect implementation of Barrier Method of synchronisation

Tags: operating-system, synchronization, barrier

Consider the following Barrier method to implement synchronization :

```
void barrier 
{
     P(s);
     process_arrived++;
     V(s);
     while(process_arrived != 3);
     P(s);
     process_left++;
     if(process_left == 3)
     {
        process_Arrived = 0;
        process_left = 0; 
      }
     V(s);
 }
```

It is known that this code does not work because of a flaw, but I am not able to find the flaw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the condition :  if (process_left == 3)

It may lead to deadlock if two barrier invocations are used in immediate  succession.

Initially, process_arrived and process_left will be '0'.

When a process arrives, it increments process_arrived and waits till maximum number of processes have arrived. After that processes are allowed to leave.

Consider the following scenario:

P1 comes and waits till process_arrived becomes 3 ( currently process_arrived = 1)
P2 comes and waits till process_arrived becomes 3 ( currently process_Arrived = 2)

Now P3 comes for execution. The condition in while loop fails and executes further, making process_left = 1 and again enters the function immediately.
It makes process_Arrived = 4 and waits in while loop.

P2 gets a chance to execute makes process_left = 2 and leaves.
P1 executes further and finds that process_left = 3, thereby making both process_arrived and process_left = 0. (Remember that P3 has already entered and is waiting at the barrier, so here a count is lost)

P1 again executes , makes process_arrived = 1 and waits.
P2 also executes again. makes process_arrived = 2 and waits.

Now every process will wait for ever. Hence a deadlock has occurred.